# How do I reset an existing CVS tag to point to the new revisions of the files?

Tags: cvs

I'm not exactly sure how I got myself into this situation, but essentially, I had modified an existing codebase and added some new files and few months back, and when I went to check it in, I created a new tag and committed. That worked fine.

Fast forward to now, when I found a bug in the old code. I fixed it, and committed, thinking that the tag would be updated to point to the updated revisions. It wasn't. I then tried using rtag, and it worked for some, but not all of the files I modified. Is there any way to take the exisiting tag and just have it point to the new revisions of the files?